# How to redirect before ajax request success response

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms, post

**Background:** If is post a form, the process is of 4-5 minutes. And I can't wait for that process. I don't need a response from the server. So I want the process should be handled by the server at the backend, the user should be redirected to another page after submitting the form.
Here is my code.

```
    $("form#form").submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();    
    var formData = new FormData(this);

    var call = $.ajax({
        url: '',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });

    window.location.replace("http:localhost/members/maga-process.php");
});
```

Problems to handle:

- the user just clicks to submit the form. and a post request should be sent to a URL and the user is redirected to another page without waiting for success response(because the process is of 4-5 minutes).

Comment: Whats the problem? You are correct in that you don't need to wait for the response.

Comment: I want to redirect to the new page ( maga-process.php) from this page where I submit the form. I can only redirect once the process is completed.

Comment: Have you tested this theory of yours?

Comment: yes i have tested alot of methods. i have also used jquery post method.

Comment: i think you need a background process, In ajax you will only activate it

Comment: yes right. can you plz guide me, how can I do that?

Comment: The Ajax should call a PHP script which will put the request for this action into a database table (for example, it doesn't have to be). And then you need a Cron job set to run regularly which checks for new jobs listed in the table and processes them. The Cron can trigger another PHP script or a program written in any other language you choose

Comment: Thanks, @ADyson. I got your point. but it's a long process... And for me, it should be the last option.

Comment: `but it's a long process`...what is? You mean the task you want the code to do? Or you mean the process of creating the architecture I've just mentioned would be long? BTW you don't really have any other options, so I'm not sure what the problem is. This is the standard way to handle such a situation. If you fire an AJAX request but then move away from the page, you run the risk that the server will simply stop processing it. So you can't do that, you need to make the server pass the task to a background process which is guaranteed to run correctly.

Comment: Thanks, @ADyson I agree with you. I think you are right, it might be risky if I do so, that I planned before.